# Changing font colors in PHP when calling a function

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
    echo get_menu_tree(0);       
?>
```

Here's my PHP tag wherein I'm calling a function that displays all the data (text) from PHP MySQL Database.

The default color when I'm calling the function is white. How do I change the font color into Black?

I just updated my post. Here's my return function. Any ideas?

```
<?php

function get_menu_tree($parentID)
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM category where parentID='" .$parentID . "' ";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

        $menu .="<li><a href='index.php?page=category&categoryID=".$row['categoryID']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";


        $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['categoryID'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively

        $menu .= "</li>";



    }

    return $menu;
}

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: "The default color when I'm calling the function is white"  Find the CSS that is doing this and change it.  Or add a CSS rule specific to this section of output that overrides the rule that is doing this.  Text is black by default, so you have something that is intentionally making it white.

Comment: Just a general comment - you really don't want to use global variables.  Like, ever.  Pass `$con` as a parameter like `$parentId`.  Why?  Because global variables are really, really hard to debug/fix/maintain, and lead to what's known as spaghetti code, where various components of your app are tied together in ways that aren't easily seen due to the fact that important parts aren't shared through the argument lists of functions/object methods.  Using the `global` keyword is an immediate sign of doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function get_menu_tree($parentID) 
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parentID = '$parentID'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $menu = "<li><a href='index.php?page=category&categoryID =".$row['categoryID']."'></a></li>";
    }
    $menu = "<ul>".$menu."</ul>";
    return $menu;
}
?>
```

But if you want to output a table with the data i personaly would just use a php file and use this code

```
<?php
     //Define $con here and put the php scripts you need in this file or use require(path/to/file.php) or include(path/to/file.php) to include other php documents
?>

//Some HTML... 

<ul>
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parentID = '$parentID'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=category&categoryID =".$row['categoryID']."'></a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean something like this?

Comment: <?php

  <span style="color:#000000;"><?php echo get_menu_tree(0); ?></span>
    
 ?>

I'm having an error tho. I just need to change the font color

Comment: Whether or not that will work as expected/desired depends on what is being returned by the function.

Comment: If you php function returns a string or number you can use the code I used in the code block.

Comment: @RojenAgustin No, you can't put HTML in a PHP script. You need to end the PHP block `?>` or output the HTML with a PHP function `echo`, `print`, etc.

Comment: I posted by return function below. Can you kindly look at it? Thank you!

Comment: Just a typo. My I updated my post with the return function. Can you kindly look at it? Thank you!

Comment: @RojenAgustin just updated my answer, just look at it, if this does not help you, it would be nice if you could provide a little more information about what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

Let me be a little more generic instead of going straight to the point:

- You can think at PHP as a lnaguage to manipulate text effectively and the kind of text you can manipulate is quite generic: in fact you can use PHP to produce any kind of text, also C, C++, ... code even if it is typically used in the Web context hence to produce HTML and CSS
- As a result of this, PHP in itself has no *understanding* of the text it's manipulating, from its perspective it's just text
- What you are interested in (color of an element) is something that is defined at CSS level, not at PHP level, however PHP is the tool you can use to produce CSS
- To be slightly more complete (and conclude) this **Appearance Semantic** is defined at CSS level and requires HTML to define the structure first: the example provided by @TSteffenmann is in fact a specific case of this and it's hence correct but you can do something even more generic (i.e. instead of a span you can use p, ... whatever you want and use CSS to style)